# I'm trying the code and don't know i get error on somepage like no object attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** a website call yellowpages it was working fine but now, I'm facing some problems after few pages or on start page i got the error of anything even they give the variable is not define error and i know the variable is in the code. here is my code please look at it sometime i got the one same  address on whole excel.
Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
pagenum=15
maxpage = 30

while pagenum <= maxpage:
    newsu =pagenum
    newsu = str(newsu)
    csvname = 'dealers'+newsu+'.csv';
    csvfile = open(csvname , 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Business name', 'phone' , 'address' , 'website'] )
    page = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=car%20dealer&geo_location_terms=Queens%2C%20NY&page={}'.format(pagenum)
    pagenum = pagenum+1
    source= requests.get(page).text
    x=0;
    soup= BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    ParentDiv=soup.find('div' , class_='organic')
     
    for PParentDiv in ParentDiv.find_all('div' , class_='v-card'):
        
        ress=addr=''
        PName = PParentDiv.find('a' , class_='business-name').span.text
        
        phone = PParentDiv.find('div' , class_='phones phone primary').text

        ress = PParentDiv.find('div' , class_='street-address').get_text()
        
        addr = PParentDiv.find('div' , class_='locality').get_text()
        address = ress + ' ' + addr
            
            
        x=x+1
        print(x)
            
        try:
            
            website = PParentDiv.find('a' , class_='track-visit-website').get('href')
        
        except Exception as e:
            website=''
       
        csv_writer.writerow([PName, phone , address , website])   
        
            
    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: can you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: Sure here it is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python36\scraper\sc.py", line 28, in <module>
    ress = PParentDiv.find('div' , class_='street-address').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Manually go to the page with a browser and select "view page source", then search for 'street-address'. Your error code suggests that the div with that class doesn't exists. It is possible that we site did some work and changed the class name -- that is something you have to deal with when scraping.

Comment: i did the same  but all the section have div with street address class.

Comment: See my answer below -- you may simply be looking at a case when they are all there and missing the case when they are not.

Comment: I've one doubt maybe it is because of slow speed of page? like address take time to load when i try to open the site.? can we slow down the process until we get the address

Comment: I don't want to say that is impossible, but I think requests waits until it gets back the entire page - so it shouldn't matter. Hopefully you are using a good IDE such as PyCharm. You can put a break point right after your requests.get statement and see what it returns you. You should be able to note whether the class name is in the returned text. I think you will find that it isn't there.

Comment: Add a statement right after request.get, if not 'street-address' in source: print("Missing"), and see what you get.

Comment: That's what i try to do earlier and that the class is still there? i got this error when I've multiple page to scrap when i scrap page individually it runs fine  could you please check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try/except to deal with cases in which the class doesn't exist;

eg.

```
try: 
    ress = PParentDiv.find('div' , class_='street-address').get_text()
except AttributeError:
    ress = None
```

It may be that when there is no street address, the page simply doesn't include that DIV - and you seemingly randomly get an error.